# How to increase the font size in the utility panel and .plist file

Tags: xcode

I am not talking about font size in the code editing area, but the font size in the utility area or .plist file is crazily small. My eyes hurts when reading those tiny small words. Anyone knows how to increase the font size in those area? BTW, I am using Xcode 7. Thanks.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: But if someone could let me know how to increase its font size, it could make my "programming" life a lot better. It really drives crazy looking at those tiny fonts. It's another way to help programmers :-)

Comment: Maybe try https://apple.stackexchange.com/ insteaad?